# Trying to sort a column from user input

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

So I'm trying to find the min and max from a particular column in a set of files and then putting those values in two text files. The column that I want my script to sort though is the number inputted from the user. This is my code and it works for the most part except it's giving me the min and max for each column. How do I fix this?

```
echo "Please enter a column you wish to change: "
read userinput
if [ ${userinput} -gt 10 ]; then
      echo "Error"
else
      sort -nk${userinput} Node{1..4}.txt | awk 'NR==1{print $userinput}' > result.txt
      sort -nk${userinput} Node{1..4}.txt | awk 'END{print $userinput}' > results.txt
fi
```

The ${userinput} in the sort part is supposed to be the column the user specified, so for example if the user put in "10" then it would be sort -nk10. The script works for the most part except it's giving me the min and max of all the columns when it checks through all four of my text files that I specified. How do I fix it so that it is only giving me the min and max of the column specified by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not read the value of a shell variable in awk. Uste the `-v` option for setting an awk variable.

```
userinput=4
# This will not work
awk 'BEGIN {print "UserInput=" $userinput}'
# This works
awk -v colnr=$userinput 'BEGIN {print "UserInput=" colnr }'
```

You can use this like

```
echo "A B C D E F" | awk -v colnr=$userinput '{print "Col " colnr "=" $colnr }'
```

Comment: When I do this the result.txt and results.txt files just give me the value the user inputted (so if the user inputted the number 3 then those files just have the number 3 in them)

Comment: Added example line `A B C D E F`

Comment: I understand now, thank you! It works like how I needed it to!